# OpenLDAP ACL permissions for cn=config

Tags: ssl, openldap

I am trying to add ssl certificates in `olcTLSCertificateFile`.

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/openldap/certs/file.crt

dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile 
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/openldap/certs/file.key
```

I had created these certificates as `Single Sign-on` using OpenSSL on CentOS7.

```
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -out /etc/openldap/certs/file.crt -keyout /etc/openldap/certs/file.key -days 3650
```

Here are the ACL permissions I have added to the using

```
#monitor.ldif
dn: olcDatabase={1}monitor,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external, cn=auth" read by dn.base="cn=Manager,dc=domain,dc=com" read by * none
```

In last, I am modifying the file and getting error:

```
ldapmodify -x -W -D "cn=Manager,dc=domain,dc=com"  -H ldapi:/// -f certs.ldif

Enter LDAP Password: 

 modifying entry "cn=config"
```

> ldap_modify: Insufficient access (50)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution. Just changed the order of key and crt file and it worked.

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile 
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/openldap/certs/file.key

dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/openldap/certs/file.crt
```